# Web app, load image into memory to get width

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have a web application that displays large thumbnails.  The layout is built on the server.  What's the best way, server side, to load the images into memory as I want to adjust the row layout depending on the cumulative width of the images?  All I need to know is the width, but this can vary image by image?

I'm thinking, create control, load image, get the width, then clear memory?

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just load it from the file. No need to create a control. See [this Bitmap constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx).

For example:

```
int width;
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename))
{
    width = bmp.Width;
}
```